# What if I add multiple dependency in React's useEffect second parameter?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For example if I make a `useEffect` hook as `useEffect(() => {...},[a,b])`. Will the `useEffect` get fired if one of [a,b] changes or when both [a,b] changes ?

Comment: no idea, so I filed https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15068, which in the future I would highly recommend you also do. If the official documentation doesn't cover a question, you are almost guaranteed not to be the only person to wonder about whatever you're wondering about, and asking the people who make the thing you use to improve the docs is of great benefit to everyone.

Comment: Or, if possible, just test it yourself : )

Comment: But when we test it, it may give an answer but you can't test all the edge cases and be sure about it. Why not just add a line in the documentation to remove all the doubts.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It will fire when either one changes. The way to think of it is that you are telling React:

> `a` and `b` are the things that I am using inside this effect, so if either of them
>   change, my effect will need to cleanup the old version and re-execute with the updated values.

Here's a simple example that allows you to see the behavior:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [dependency1, setDependency1] = useState(1);
  const [dependency2, setDependency2] = useState(1);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log("only dependency1", dependency1, dependency2);
    },
    [dependency1]
  );
  useEffect(
    () => {
      console.log("dependency1 and dependency2", dependency1, dependency2);
    },
    [dependency1, dependency2]
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDependency1(prev => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        Change dependency1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDependency2(prev => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        Change dependency2
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDependency1(prev => prev + 1);
          setDependency2(prev => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        Change both
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit useEffect dependencies]

Comment: Looks like it gets fired when one of them changes. But why the documentation is not clear about it ? May be in future they will be clear about it. Nevertheless thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: It isn’t easy for the React team (who live and breathe this stuff) to predict what will and won’t be obvious to people. The documentation explains the purpose of the array (from which one could infer what the behavior should be). Describing all the edge cases in detail can make it harder to find the key concepts and make things appear more complicated than they are. If you think the documentation should be improved, submit a pull request with the changes that would have helped you understand this.

Comment: Is it possible to do it the other way? What if I do want an effect that only fires when two or more variables are all changed?

Comment: @nullromo I would need further context to understand what kind of problem you are trying to solve. I recommend creating your own question where you can provide additional details along with code and a sandbox demonstrating your issue.

Comment: I think the answer to my question is you just lump all the state variables together into 1 object and put that object in the dependency array. Then there's technically only 1 state variable and you can modify many of its attributes at once to get only 1 effect triggered.